# Vue 404 on refresh in 'production'

Tags: vue.js

I say production, but it's running locally in a docker container. My backend is Django.

I'm having a little trouble with my vue app. submitting a form, or refreshing the page results in a 404 error. My data gets posted, but I have to go back to the beginning and navigate back to see my page. My searching led me to believe that using

> history: createWebHistory()

might solve my problem, but the result is the same.

My /router/index.js:

```
...
{
  path: '/dashboard/users/:id',
  name: 'Users',
  component: Users,
  meta: { 
    requireLogin: true
  }
},

]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { 
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireLogin) && !store.state.isAuthenticated) { 
    next('/log-in')
  } else { 
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

Lots of topic seem to involve netify, or apache, of which I'm running neither. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be missing a catch-all route in your router configuration. Without seeing your full router configuration, it's hard to say for sure, but something like this might work:

```
{
  path: '*',
  component: NotFound
}
```

This will catch any routes that don't match any of your other routes, and render the NotFound component.